# StringBuffer is not been printed correctly

Tags: java, string, sockets, inputstream, bufferedreader

I am trying to read some data from a InputStream, and then put them into a StringBuffer to print it.

I put this code in the main method.

My problem is that the StringBuffer is only printed when I am debugging the code, when I run it normally it isnt been printed.

My code:

```
Socket s = new Socket();
String host = "";
PrintWriter s_out = null;
BufferedReader s_in = null;
InputStream in = null;

s.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, 23));

//writer for socket
s_out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
//reader for socket
s_in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
in = s.getInputStream();

if(s.isConnected() == true && s.isInputShutdown() == false && s.isOutputShutdown() == false){
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    boolean found = false;
    char ch;
    int numberOfBytesThatCanBeRead = in.available();

    for(int j = 0; j < numberOfBytesThatCanBeRead; j++){
        ch = (char) s_in.read();
        //System.out.print(ch);
        sb.append(ch);
    }

    System.out.print(sb.toString());

    s_in.close();
    in.close();
    s_out.close();
    s.close();
```

The correct value of this variable is 564, but it is only returned when I debug the code, when i run normally it returns 21.

```
int numberOfBytesThatCanBeRead = in.available();
```

So, my question is: Why when I debug the code, the result of StringBuffer is correct, and when I run normally it is not ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no loop listening on the port, that means that you run through and end immediately before the other side has finished sending all its data.

When you debug that means there is enough time for it all to arrive before you try and read it.

Do the reading in a loop waiting until all the data you need has arrived.

Comment: Thanks Tim. What would be the structure of this loop ?

Comment: That depends on the protocol you are using (you have defined one right? ;) ). Often you would just loop looking for an end of stream. Really I don't see why you are doing this low level socket programming though, there are lots of higher level libraries available that will handle all of this for you.

Comment: Yes Tim, I am using Telnet Protocol. I was trying to use the Telnet library, but when i reached a part of read() method the thread was blocked. So, I started to use Socket, and it works.

Comment: Telnet isn't really what I had in mind - Telnet is basically just ASCII over TCP/IP. I meant protocol as in Google Protocol Buffers/HTTP/SOAP/etc...or even just serializing java objects and throwing them over the wire...

Comment: I read some comments about reading data from InputStream using Telnet, and almost everyone said that was having difficults. Because the InputStream read() method does not return -1 when there is no data available to read, it blocks the thread.